# Using on-send add-ins, is it possible to differentiate when a user selects "send" & "send later" within the ItemSend event handler?

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-on-send-addins?tabs=windows

I'm wondering if it's possible to extract timestamp info or any other info indicating if a user pressed "send" or "send later" for a composed message item?

Comment: To confirm, based on your description, are you trying this with Outlook on the web? In Outlook for Windows, a similar feature is "Delay Delivery", and OfficeJS doesn't provider property out of the box. The on-send add-in runs when user selects 'send'

Comment: Could you also tell more about the scenario where you want to differentiate between "send" & "send later"?

Answer (score 0):

`OfficeJS` doesn't provide any property or method for that out of the box. But you can use EWS APIs from your add-in. See [Call web services from an Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/web-services) for more information.

You can get an extended property values (for example, `PR_DEFERRED_SEND_TIME`) using EWS, see [How to: Delay sending an email message by using the EWS Managed API 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/jj220496(v=exchg.80)).